# как объединить в одну строку генерируемое в нескольких fifo каналах?

Tags: linux

Один генерaтор генерит в fifo1, второй в fifo2.
Как объединить оба канала и соединить в одну строку на вход в pipe третьего процесса?
`cat fifo1 fifo2` не работает
`paste fifo1 fifo2` выводит, но с пробелами между выводами, а нужно слитно, добавление `sed s/' '//g` не помогло.
Как это сделать? И можно ли если fifo каналов больше двух?

если какой вариант не просто объединить `fifo1` к `fifo2`, а перебрать все варианты между ними?

Comment: скорей всего стоит решать [проблему X](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4900/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-yx) и не пользоваться именованными каналами...

Comment: `paste -d '' fifo1 fifo2` , если нужно строки попарно объединить без разделителя...

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось так:

```
cat fifo1 > fifo3 | cat fifo2 > fifo3
```

вроде пашет

Comment: А у меня почему-то так не пашет. То есть если запустить отдельно еще `cat fifo3`, то работает, но строки не объединяет между собой, а просто последовательно добавляет в общий список, т.е. как обычно как и `cat file1 file2` - строки из file2 добавляются после строк file1, а надо чтобы каждая строка `fifo1` добавлялась к строке `fifo2`

Comment: Я сначала пишу без конца строки так: `> echo -n "Заголовок: " > fifo1` затем к строчке добавляю `> echo "данные" > fifo2`. Не знаю как вам будет удобно с **echo**?